Wifi hast stopped working since arriving in Korea?
I am traveling Asia with my Macbook 12,1 (2015) running Kubuntu 24.04, here are the specs:
Operating System: Kubuntu 24.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.27.11
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.115.0
Qt Version: 5.15.13
Kernel Version: 6.8.0-47-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 4 × Intel® Core™ i5-5257U CPU @ 2.70GHz
Memory: 15.5 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® Iris® Graphics 6100
Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
Product Name: MacBookPro12,1
System Version: 1.0

Since arriving in Korea I am having difficulty connecting to WiFi networks (public or secured)
This is what happens:

Boot machine
Login
Select network from KDE Network Manager UI
Connect to network
Internet works for about 15-30 seconds
Disconnect
Error "wlp30s0" is not available
No WiFi networks visible,
Restart machine to see networks again

Here is a condensed log from Journal
NetworkManager: device (wlp3s0) supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
NetworkManager: device (wlp3s0) state change: disconnected -> scanning
wpa_supplicant: Trying to associate with SSID 'KTX-WiFi-Free'
wpa_supplicant: Association request to the driver failed
kernel: ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_cfg80211_connect: BRCMF_C_SET_SSID failed (-52)
NetworkManager: state change: scanning -> disconnected

Full log can be found here
WiFi module:
description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 01
       serial: a4:5e:60:de:b6:3f
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmfmac driverversion=7.35.177.61 firmware=01-ea662a8c latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:80 memory:c1400000-c1407fff memory:c1000000-c13fffff

What I've tried:

Network manager service issue, stop/start
Updating drivers for broadcom
Letting machine cool-down
Use ethernet tethering (works ok)
Use wifi phone tethering (still same issue)
Tried different Wifi networks in Korea

Theories:

Laptop damaged
Incompatible Wifi networks (Wifi 6?)
Network / DNS issue
Wifi units don't like that I am a Linux host with name "typhoon"

Any ideas?

Perhaps regional settings causing problems?  What channels - and other radio related things - that are allowed varies depending on what country you are visiting. Try setting your wifi adapters regional setting to KR . iw reg set KR and check with iw reg get.
